# How to print on one line after applying a for loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops

I am having a range variable which takes a single integer and then I want to print the table of 9 till that range. So I am able to print the table of 9 successfully but I want it to be printed on a single line with space between them. May I please get an explanation on this as I am a beginner in Javascript.

This is my code

```
  let range = 3; 
    
  for (i=1; i<=range; i++) {
    final_res = 9 * i;
    console.log(final_res)
  }
```

Comment: You're executing console log 3 times (1,2,3). `console.log` prints a new line.

Answer (score 1):

Put everything in an array then print it

```js
  let range = 3; 
  const values = []
  for (i=1; i<=range; i++) {
    final_res = 9 * i;
    values.push(final_res)
  }   
  console.log(values.join())
```

Comment: In the end, I'm getting whitespace so can you please help me out in understanding this.

Comment: `console.log` prints a new line at the end it's normal

Answer (score 1):

Create a function to calculate the table. Instead of printing each result , append them with a space and print final result

```js
let range = 3;

function printTable(multiplier, multiplicant = 9) {
  let final_res = ''
  for (let i = 1; i <= multiplier; i++) {
    final_res += `${multiplicant * i} `
  }
  return final_res;
}

console.log(printTable(range))
```